# Shoulda matchers have_many with custom relation name

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rspec, shoulda

How do I test this ActiveRecord relation using **shoulda** matchers?

#### Models

```
class User < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :articles
end

class Article < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :author, class_name: 'User'
end
```

#### Test

```
describe User do
  it { should have_many(:articles) }
end
```

I'm getting the following error:

```
1) User should have many articles
     Failure/Error: it { should have_many(:articles) }
       Expected User to have a has_many association called articles (Article does not have a user_id foreign key.)
     # ./spec/models/user_spec.rb:4:in `block (2 levels) in <top (required)>'
```

So it obviously expects relation field to be named `user_id` because of User class name. I expect there has to be some test method that can be used to override this expectation like

```
it { should have_many(:articles).as(:owner) }
```

But I can't find anything like it. Am I missing something obvious?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

shoulda matchers includes a `.with_foreign_key()` option.

https://github.com/thoughtbot/shoulda-matchers#have_many

So in your example:

```
describe User do
  it { should have_many(:articles).with_foreign_key('author_id') }
end
```

Which is how your model should, I believe:

```
class User < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :articles, foreign_key: "author_id"
end
```

Comment: Spot on! I tried `with_foreign_key` before, but didn't know I had to define it in `User` model too. I thought ActiveRecord would know it by reading `Article` model. Now it passes, thanks a lot!