# Shoulda have_many with class_name, foreign_key and primary_key

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rspec, shoulda

How do I test this ActiveRecord relation using ShouldaMatchers?

### Models

```
class ViolatorUnitHistory < ActiveRecord::Base
...
  belongs_to :primary_source, class_name: Source, primary_key: :source_1_id, foreign_key: :id
  belongs_to :secondary_source, class_name: Source, primary_key: :source_2_id, foreign_key: :id
  belongs_to :tertiary_source, class_name: Source, primary_key: :source_3_id, foreign_key: :id
...
end  

class Source < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :violator_unit_histories
end
```

### Test

```
describe "relationships" do
  # Can't figure out this relationship
  it { is_expected.to have_many(:violator_unit_histories).class_name('Source').with_primary_key('source_1_id').with_foreign_key('id') }
end
```

### Current Results

```
Failures:
  1) Source relationships should have many violator_unit_histories class_name => Source
     Failure/Error: it { is_expected.to have_many(:violator_unit_histories).class_name('Source').with_primary_key('source_1_id').with_foreign_key('id') }
       Expected Source to have a has_many association called violator_unit_histories ()
     # ./spec/models/source_spec.rb:17:in `block (3 levels) in <top (required)>'
```

### Previous Results

```
it { is_expected.to have_many(:violator_unit_histories) }

Failures:
  1) Source relationships should have many violator_unit_histories
     Failure/Error: it { is_expected.to have_many(:violator_unit_histories) }
       Expected Source to have a has_many association called violator_unit_histories (ViolatorUnitHistory does not have a source_id foreign key.)
```

I saw the answer posted [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21657906/shoulda-matchers-have-many-with-custom-relation-name) for the `belongs_to` side of the test. But I can't seem to figure out he `has_many` side to these more complex tests.

Comment: Try `it { is_expected.to have_many(:violator_unit_histories) }`

Comment: Thanks @Pavan. Unfortunately no luck. I added the the output to the "Previous Results" section.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

First, it looks like your primary / foreign key relationships are a bit off here.

Starting with your model definitions:

```
class ViolatorUnitHistory < ActiveRecord::Base
...
  belongs_to :primary_source, class_name: Source, primary_key: :source_1_id, foreign_key: :id
  belongs_to :secondary_source, class_name: Source, primary_key: :source_2_id, foreign_key: :id
  belongs_to :tertiary_source, class_name: Source, primary_key: :source_3_id, foreign_key: :id
...
end  

class Source < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :violator_unit_histories
end
```

The issue here is that `:id` doesn't seem to be a foreign key, but a primary key. Conversely, `source_1_id` appears to be a foreign key defined on the `ViolatorUnitHistory` model. Is this correct?

In other words, assuming you had an instance of `Source` with associated `violator_unit_histories`, what would you expect `@source.violator_unit_histories` to return? There's nothing in your code that clearly defines what `violator_unit_histories` actually is.

This is why you're getting  this error:

> ViolatorUnitHistory does not have a source_id foreign key.

Rails is looking for a `source_id` foreign key in the `ViolatorUnitHistory` class, however, one does not exist.

Also, in your tests, you're not explicitly defining what the `subject` of your tests is. Consider using the `expect(<object>).to` syntax to make things more clear.

Comment: Thanks @anthony-e.  Yes, this was a real problem because the data set we were given to work with was not normalized at all. So it made his tricky. My co-worker added some info below that we just figured out. But I'm marking yours as the correct one since it got us on the right path,

Answer (score 1):

To piggy back what Anthony E said, the relationship between ViolatorUnitHistory => Source is clearly defined, but the reverse isn't. You can say `Violator.first.primary_source`, but `Source.first.violator_unit_histories` isn't correct because of how the database is normalized.

I would probably define each reverse relationship in a similar manner as you did the ViolatorUnitHistory => Source relationship since the ViolatorUnitHistory uses multiple fields to store a Source.id

You could add something like:

```
class Source < ActiveRecord::Base
...
  # I don't think primary_, secondary_ etc sources is a great name for these, since
  #   since it's really "History that has this as a primary source"
  has_many :primary_sources, class_name: ViolatorUnitHistory, primary_key: :id, foreign_key: :source_1_id
  has_many :secondary_sources, class_name: ViolatorUnitHistory, primary_key: :id, foreign_key: :source_2_id
  has_many :tertiary_sourcs, class_name: ViolatorUnitHistory, primary_key: :id, foreign_key: :source_3_id
...
end
```

Then your tests become something like:

```
describe "relationships" do
  expect(source).to have_many :primary_sources
  expect(source).to have_many :secondary_sources
  expect(source).to have_many :tertiary_sources
end
```

The alternative would be to normalize your database so you had a join table which included `ViolatorUnitHistory.id`, `Source.id`, and some indicator of ordinality (source_order or something, for your 1st, 2nd, 3rd)

Disclosure: I work with Chris and I've seen the actual data source so I have a little more insight into the question